# WPF Bing Maps - Zoom to Polyline

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, bing-maps, polyline

I created a WPF Bing map and added polyline I would like set the center and zoom level, which fit polyline. Like map.fitBounds(bounds).

```
MapPolyline polyline = new MapPolyline();
polyline.Stroke = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Blue);
polyline.Locations = new LocationCollection() { 
    new Location(47.6424, ,-122.3219), 
    new Location(47.8424,-122.1747), 
    new Location(47.67856,-122.130994)};

myMap.Children.Add(polyline);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get an `IEnumerable<Location>` from [`LocationCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bing/wpf-control/hh709539(v=msdn.10)?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) of your polyline and then use an overload of [`SetView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bing/wpf-control/hh709344(v=msdn.10)?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) to zoom to the locations. This overload allows you to set a margin as well.

```
myMap.SetView(polyline.Locations.Cast<Location>(), 
    new System.Windows.Thickness(0), 0);
```

Or you can create a [`LocationRect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bing/wpf-control/hh709540(v=msdn.10)?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) from  [`LocationCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bing/wpf-control/hh709539(v=msdn.10)?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) of your polyline and then use another overload of [`SetView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bing/wpf-control/hh709341(v=msdn.10)?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) to zoom to the rectangle.

```
myMap.SetView(new LocationRect(polyline.Locations));
```

**Exampel 1 - IEnumerable<Location>**

```
MapPolyline polyline = new MapPolyline();
polyline.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
polyline.Locations = new LocationCollection() {
    new Location(47.6424, -122.3219),
    new Location(47.8424,-122.1747),
    new Location(47.67856,-122.130994)};
myMap.Children.Add(polyline);
myMap.SetView(polyline.Locations.Cast<Location>(), 
    new System.Windows.Thickness(0), 0);
```

**Example 2 - LocationRect**

```
MapPolyline polyline = new MapPolyline();
polyline.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
polyline.Locations = new LocationCollection() {
    new Location(47.6424, -122.3219),
    new Location(47.8424,-122.1747),
    new Location(47.67856,-122.130994)};
myMap.Children.Add(polyline);
myMap.SetView(new LocationRect(polyline.Locations));
```

[image]